# how to iterate through all the columns in sqlite using fmdb in objective-c

Tags: fmdb

I need to do a search on all the columns, so instead of specifying each column name in the where clause I would like to create a method that can search through all the columns.

```
-(void) fillSomeobjectNames:(NSString *)filter
{
    FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];

    [db open];

    NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id, name, imagefile FROM %@ %@", mainTableName, filter];
    FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:sql];
    while([results next]) 
    {
        Someobject *someobject = [[Someobject alloc] init];
        [someobject setID:[results intForColumn:@"id"]];
        [someobject setName:[results stringForColumn:@"name"]];
        NSString *iconName = [[results stringForColumn:@"imagefile"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".jpg" withString:@""];
        [someobject setIconPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-ico.jpg",iconName]];
        [someobjects someobject];
    }

    [db close];
}
```

'filter' can be 'WHERE remark=[searchText] AND description=[searchText] AND so on...'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think this can be done with a single SELECT statement. The best way to get column names is `PRAGMA table_info(table_name)`, unfortunately this cannot be used in the `SELECT` statements, so you need one additional `SELECT` to get the column names, and then you can build your sql and do what you want:

```
-(void) fillSomeobjectNames:(NSString *)filter
    {
        FMDatabase *db = [FMDatabase databaseWithPath:databasePath];

        [db open];

        FMResultSet columnNamesSet* = [db executeQuery:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"PRAGMA table_info(%@)", mainTableName]];
        NSMutableArray* columnNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        while ([columnNamesSet next]) {
            [columnNames addObject:[columnNamesSet stringForColumn:@"name"]];
        }
        // put whatever you need to look for as mySearchPhrase
        NSString* partToAppend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"=%@ OR ", @"mySearchPhrase"];
        NSString* filter = [columnNames componentsJoinedByString:partToAppend];
        filter = [filter stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"=%@", @"mySearchPhrase"]];

        // now your sql would look like this
        NSString *sql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT id, name, imagefile FROM %@ WHERE %@", mainTableName, filter];
        FMResultSet *results = [db executeQuery:sql];
        while([results next]) 
        {
            Someobject *someobject = [[Someobject alloc] init];
            [someobject setID:[results intForColumn:@"id"]];
            [someobject setName:[results stringForColumn:@"name"]];
            NSString *iconName = [[results stringForColumn:@"imagefile"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@".jpg" withString:@""];
            [someobject setIconPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-ico.jpg",iconName]];
            [someobjects someobject];
        }

        [db close];
    }
```

Note that I moved `WHERE` word out of the filter, and also I used `OR` instead of `AND`, which is what I think you intended to do.

One additional thing to keep in mind is the data type in each column. You compare each one to a string, but is each column in your table of type text? The pragma statement that I used also returns the type of the given column (in the column named *type*), so you could use that to filter the columns that are of type *text*.

Comment: works great. I just had to replace "=%@ OR " with " LIKE '%%%@%%' OR "

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for above answer, bellow code for swift 3. This code is display all the column of table.

```
    let db = FMDatabase(path: Util.getPath(databasePath))
    guard db != nil else { return }

    db!.open()

   let resultSet: FMResultSet! = db!.executeQuery("PRAGMA table_info(tableName)",withArgumentsIn: nil)

   let marrInfo : NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray()
   if (resultSet != nil) {
       while resultSet.next() {
           let aDict : NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
           aDict.setValue(resultSet.string(forColumn: "cid"), forKey: "cid")
           aDict.setValue(resultSet.string(forColumn: "name"), forKey: "name")
           aDict.setValue(resultSet.string(forColumn: "type"), forKey: "type")
           aDict.setValue(resultSet.string(forColumn: "notnull"), forKey: "notnull")
           aDict.setValue(resultSet.string(forColumn: "pk"), forKey: "pk")
           print(aDict)
           marrInfo.add(aDict)
       }
   }
   db!.close()
```